# Get uid after successfully signing in (Swift + Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a very basic sign in app in swift to practice firebase. I've come up with this:

```
@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Assigns and checks if the email and password aren't empty
    if let inpt_email = emailField.text, let inpt_password = passwordField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: inpt_email, password: inpt_password, completion: { (user, error) in
            //Checks if the user exists
            if error != nil {
                //ERROR: No user found
                self.signInLabel.text = "Invalid User! Please Try Again"
            } else {
                //Sign Success
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: self)
            }


        })
    }

} //End of signInPressed
// END: SIGN IN BUTTON
```

The **//Sign Success** part doesn't actually get any data at all, it just checks if the input matches any User that is registered in Firebase, and then segue to the next page. What I want to do is to:

1. Get the uid of the user which matches both the emailField and passwordField in the Firebase Auth.
2. Somewhat registers that uid as "Currently Signed In" in the app itself for future reference.

I tried reading the Firebase Documentation and all I got was this:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  // User is signed in.
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // ...
}
```

And this:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
  // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
  // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
}
```

I'm new to Firebase so I basically don't understand how to use this, although I kind of get what it means, I just don't know what it's for or how to put it in action.

Thanks!

Comment: do this user?.uid before self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: self)

Comment: @rv7284 Thanks! :D One more thing, how can I register this as a global variable in the app so I can use it on other view controllers? Like after signing in it passes that variable to the "toHome" view.

Comment: Store it in UserDefaults

Comment: @rv7284 Thanks again! Last question sir, I tried printing the user?.uid and it gave me "Optional("123hjgsdj2y3j1")". How can I unwrap the "Optional" word sir ? I only want the -123hjgsdj2y3j1- part.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if let user = user {
     print(user.uid)
}
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.